# Merge multiple (more than two!) PowerPoint presentations into one

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm collecting status reports from 20 different project managers and each of them sends a PowerPoint presentation containing just one slide with a status summary. I would like to merge all these files into one PowerPoint presentation with one slide for each project (instead of 20 .pptx documents with one slide each as I have now).

I know that you can easily merge two presentations using New Slide --> Reuse Slide but since you can't select more than one presentation at a time it doesn't help me. The same goes for using the Review --> Combine since I can only compare two presentations simultaneaously.

Any suggestions of how to do this?

Note: I'm using PowerPoint 2010 but I appreciate answers using any version since it might still help...

Comment: http://www.sobolsoft.com/pptjoin/

Comment: does the end product need to be a powerpoint presentation?

Comment: Hi, it would be OK with a pdf as well but a ppt is definitely preferable.

Answer (score -2):

One option is to open multiple slide shows at once and copy slides between them:

- In File Explorer select them all, right click and choose open.
- In PowerPoint do View -> Window -> Arrange all.
- Copy slides between presentations using drag and drop or cut and
  paste etc.

[image: PowerPoint with multiple presentations open]

Comment: That's how I've done it but it's quite tedious work to do every week.... =)

Comment: User clearly doesn't want addition of files one by one.